# In Google Sheets, how do I input a grading scale?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a rubric in sheets. It calculates the grade and turns it into an average in two different cells. I want to take the average cell and use a formula (in the next cell) that would plug in the grading scale and give a letter grade. Is this possible? I’m new to the formulas.

Here’s the grading scale I need to add. [image]

Comment: The vlookup works quite well, you could also use an IF or IFS statement.

Answer (score 2):

You can set up your rubric in some cells like I've done below and use the [VLOOKUP](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318?hl=en) formula. Make sure that the scores are on the left, where each listed score is the *minimum* for the grade it receives. Also note that they're sorted from low (F grade) to high (A grade).

[image]

Then the VLOOKUP formula takes your input grade, the range you've set up as above (referenced absolutely - this means it's got dollar signs when we're writing it down, and won't change when you copy & paste the formula), and the "index" of the range we want to get from the formula (the grade is the 2nd from the left, so we put down 2). It looks like this:

[image]

If you've got any questions you can find my contact info on my [profile](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/195994/tom-appsautodev).

Answer (score 0):

Easier way to do this is use [IFS function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7014145).

```
=IFS(A1>92, "A", A1>84, "B", A1>74, "C", A1>66, "D",A1<67,"F")
```

As per the support documentation, it returns the value of the first true condition. So, if my score is 66 it will process sequentially and return F as it will be the first true condition.